# error when burning Ubuntu 12.10 to a disk

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, dvd, dvd-burning, ubuntu-12.10

I am getting this error 0XC0AA0301 when trying to burn Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 to a DVD or CD using the windows 7 built in burner. I have googled this error and it has not been much help.

What causes this error? Bad disk? bad burner?

Should I try a third party DVD burner utility?

Comment: how do I do a hash check? Im using memorex DVDs

Comment: Download this program and get the Ubuntu hash wherever you downloaded it from - http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/MD5-Check.shtml

Comment: @ekaj Ok the checksum matches so its not corrupted

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas besides telling you to look for driver updates and try Microsoft's troubleshooter - the only other thing I can tell you is to use a different program to burn the DVDs, but that is just a work around and doesn't fix the initial problem.

Answer (score -1):

You get this error:

```
//
// MessageId: E_IMAPI_UNEXPECTED_RESPONSE_FROM_DEVICE
//
// MessageText:
//
// The write failed because the drive returned error information that could not be recovered from.
//
#define E_IMAPI_UNEXPECTED_RESPONSE_FROM_DEVICE ((HRESULT)0xC0AA0301L)
```

Your HDD where you stored the ISO has some issues. Check it with chkdsk. You should also check the hashes of the ISO. Maybe the ISO is corrupted.

Comment: The "HDD has some issues" part would make people worry. It's either an ISO or CD problem, else he'd be posting different questions.

Comment: @ekaj +1 I know the Hard Drive is fine